# How to echo color using AWK

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have this:

```
cm_env(){
 env | grep 'cm_' | while read line; do
    echo "$line" | awk -F'=' '{print $1 $2}'
 done;
}
```

I want to print something like this:

```
env_var1=this_is_in_blue
env_var2=this_is_in_blue_too
env_var3=this_is_colored_blue
```

do I have to use something other than AWK to do this?

The problem is double quotes don't seem to work:

```
export cm_color_gray='\033[1;30m'
export cm_color_cyan='\033[1;36m'

cm_env(){
 env | grep 'cm_' | while read line; do
    echo "$line" | awk -F'=' '{print $1 $cm_color_cyan $2 $cm_color_no_color}'
 done;
}
```

I tried this:

```
echo "$line" | awk -F'=' "{print \$1 $cm_color_cyan \$2 $cm_color_no_color}"
```

but I got:

> awk: 1: unexpected character '\'

is there a way to do this using awk?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57451086/1745001 for how to create and use arrays of foreground and background colors in awk.

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass the colors as awk variables:

```
env | awk -v b='\033[1;36m' -v r='\033[0m' -F= '/cm_/{OFS="="; print $1,b$2r}'
```

Alternatively using tput:

```
env | awk -v b="$(tput setaf 6)" -v r="$(tput sgr0)" -F= '/cm_/{OFS="="; print $1,b$2r}'
```

Comment: `op` is better than `sgr0` if one is only wanting to deal in colour changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` as well for coloring output:

```
env |grep cm_ |grep -o '^[^=]*=[^=]*' |GREP_COLORS="sl=1;36:ms=1;0" grep '[^=]*='
```